# Finding the memory leak in ResizeImage

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I am getting a memory leak - oom exception - at `using (var ergebnis = ResizeImage(Bitmap.FromFile(f), 1, 1))`

Where is the memory leak, where is a dispose missing?

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("datenbank.sqlite");
m_dbConnection =
new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=datenbank.sqlite;Version=3;");
m_dbConnection.Open();
string sql = "CREATE TABLE verbindungen (farbeR NUMERIC, farbeG NUMERIC, farbeB NUMERIC, Dateiname TEXT)";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
int k = 0;
foreach (var f in files)
{
    k++;
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        this.Text = "Datei "+k+ " von "+files.Length+", Fehler: " + fehler;
    });

    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(f, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var ergebnis = ResizeImage(Bitmap.FromFile(f), 1, 1))
        {
            Color ds = ergebnis.GetPixel(0, 0);
            //
            using (var command2 = new SQLiteCommand())
            {
                sql = "INSERT INTO verbindungen VALUES(" + ds.R + ", " + ds.G + ", " + ds.B + ", '" + f + "')";
                command2.CommandText = sql;
                command2.Connection = m_dbConnection;
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
    }

    try
    {

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            fehler++;
        });
        //
    }
    //MessageBox.Show(f + ": " + abstand(ds,vergleichsfarbe));
}
```

with

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
{
    var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

    destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
    {
        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Low;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.None;

        using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
        {
            wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
            graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
        }
    }

    return destImage;
}
```

Comment: How large is your source image?  How much memory do you have?  What line is throwing the error?

Comment: @KirkWoll The program itself grows bigger and bigger. The images range from 100KB to 4MB. I have 8GB. `using (var ergebnis = ResizeImage(Bitmap.FromFile(f), 1, 1))` is throwing the error.

Comment: It seems like you aren't disposing of the bitmap you pass into `ResizeImage`, no?

Comment: Since you won't need it afterwards adding `image.Dispose()` before the `return destImage;` should do..

Comment: @TaW That solved it.

Comment: @KirkWoll Doesn't `using` take care of that?

Comment: @VitalisHommel, where are you applying `using` on the `image` parameter?

Comment: @KirkWoll `using (var ergebnis = ResizeImage(Bitmap.FromFile(f), 1, 1))`

Comment: @VitalisHommel, see my answer for an elaboration.

Comment: Can you tell me what object causes the memory leak? Using a memory profiler for this is - like - a 10 second job. For you, as you have the running code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
using (var ergebnis = ResizeImage(Bitmap.FromFile(f), 1, 1))
```

Creates a new bitmap (a disposable resource) on `Bitmap.FromFile`.  That argument is never disposed of in `ResizeImage`. Most idiomatic is to dispose at the callsite, so you would probably best be off refactoring the code to:

```
using (var image = Bitmap.FromFile(f))
using (var ergebnis = ResizeImage(image, 1, 1))
```

That way, both will get disposed.  From your comments, it seems you are confusing your original code, which was disposing of the *return* value of `ResizeImage` with the need to *also* dispose of the argument you pass *into* your method.